# Is there a way of indenting table in markdown

Tags: javascript, markdown, showdown

I'm using the showdown.js 1.7.3 for markdown

I want to be able to indent tables in a list, is there a way of doing this with showdown, if not does anyone know of any other markdown library where it is possible to indent tables in a list[image]

Comment: Unfortunately markdown does not support this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it with showdown. Check [the demo here](http://demo.showdownjs.com/#/-%20foo%0A%0A-%20bar%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20foo%20%7C%20bar%20%7C%20baz%20%7C%0A%20%20%20%20%7C-----%7C-----%7C-----%7C%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20bla%20%7C%20bli%20%7C%20blu%20%7C%0A%0A-%20baz)

Here's also a snippet showing how to do it.

```js
var conv = new showdown.Converter({tables: true});
var html = conv.makeHtml(document.getElementById('src').value);
document.getElementById('otp').value = html;
document.getElementById('otp2').innerHTML = html;
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
th {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

th, td{
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/1.8.3/showdown.js"></script>
<textarea id="src">
- foo

    | foo | bar | baz |
    |-----|-----|-----|
    | bla | bli | blu |

- baz
</textarea><br>
<textarea id="otp"></textarea><br>
<div id="otp2"></div>
```